# jQuery clientside datepicker not staying open

Tags: c#, jquery

i am looking for an asp.net calendar server control but client side. it should ideally have the next and back buttons for the months.

i am aware that there is jQuery date picker but it that opens only when clicked on an input control, i want it open always.

can someone please let me know if that possible with the jQuery date picker or another control that can do the same?

Comment: Just instatiate the jQuery datepicker on a [div instead of an input](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline), and it's always open ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`inline`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline) feature of [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Instead of an input you have to use a `div` for datepicker. If you want to save data to a `hidden` field or some other input, you should use [`altField`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field) feature. So the final code may be like this;

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="alternate" />
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        altField: "#alternate"
    });
});
```